# VLookup() with Excel VBA - Number of values to look up is variable

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a need to use vlookup in File A that references a dataset with two columns (user and country) in File B.

The number of users in column A of File A varies each time the vlookup is done so I need some VBA code that takes that into account.  What I have so far was built with the macro recorder and works fine so long as the same number of users exists each time the macro is run, which isn't the case.

Here's the code I have so far that does the vlookup and then autofills it on down to row 113.  Like I said this works until I end up with 114+ users and at that point the vlookups just stop.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[AD Data 9-8-15.xls]showAllUsersReport'!C1:C2,2,FALSE)"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B113"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Do I need to mod this code or insert something entirely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip the [Range.AutoFill method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx) and just write the formula in all at once.

```
dim lr as long
with activesheet
    lr = .cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row
    .range(.cells(2, 2), .cells(lr, 2)).FormulaR1C1 = _
       "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[AD Data 9-8-15.xls]showAllUsersReport'!C1:C2,2,FALSE)"
    .range("C2:C" & lr).formula = "=TODAY()-1"
    'for a static date (one that will not change tomorrow) use the following instead
    '.range("C2:C" & lr) = Date - 1
end with
```

I could not tell where your formula actually *started* from your sample. This *starts* in B2 and fills columns B down to the last cell in column A. It looks like your sample *might* actually start in B1 but I could not be sure.

Comment: Wow, perfect on the first try!  Thank you!

I was hoping I could take the correct answer and modify it to take other actions down to the last row with data.  

For example this bit of code enters yesterday's date into column C starting with row 2:

Comment: The `lr` variable holds the row with the last non-blank value in column A. Nothing else is important as column A is used in the VLOOKUP. If `lr` was 99 then that `.range(.cells(2, 2), .cells(lr, 2))` is the same as saying `range("B2:B99")`. The start and end are defined with the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx).

Comment: Ack... not sure what happened on that last comment.  Text got jacked up.  

For example this bit of code enters yesterday's date into column C starting with row 2 but is limited to the number of rows that had data in column A when I recorded the macro:
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(TODAY())-1"

How can I fix this to do what I want it to do down through the rows that have data in column A?

Comment: Column C would be referenced like `.range(.cells(2, 3), .cells(lr, 3))` or alternately as I've shown above. I also included a way to get a static date that will not change if that is preferred.

Comment: You win again Jeeped!  I added your code for the date and it just worked first time.  I was also able to mod it slightly to do one more thing I needed to have happen.  Somehow that worked too!

Thanks very much for the prompt replies!